# Firebase check user already logged in and different screens

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

So in my main.dart i want to check if the user is logged in already then redirect the user to HomeScreen with his userID and if not redirect the user to SignIn page.

```
    Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Get the firebase user
    final firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    String id = firebaseUser!.uid;
// Assign widget based on availability of currentUser
    if (firebaseUser != null) {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen(userId: id)));
      print('User already logged in');
    } else {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignIn()));
      print('User must SignIn');
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting the error
"The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Widget', is a potentially non-nullable type.
Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end."

Answer (score 2):

This method should return a widget. In both the cases its only getting navigated, so you can write a return SizedBox.shrink() like

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Get the firebase user
    final firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    String id = firebaseUser!.uid;
// Assign widget based on availability of currentUser
    if (firebaseUser != null) {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen(userId: id)));
      print('User already logged in');
     
    } else {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignIn()));
      print('User must SignIn');
    }
     return SizedBox.shrink();//<-----here
  }
```